# Please give an advice over which data structure should I use

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

The code is in C. I have two type of objects (`structs`) that have parent-child relationship, one parent-type can have `0` or more child-types, a child can't have its own children. I need `O(1)` parent lookup (by `uID` struct member) and child lookup (also by `uID` struct member) without knowing who's its parent. Once I've got a pointer to a parent, I want to be able to iterate through its children. And when I have a pointer to a child, I want to be able to know who's its parent. During the execution of the program any child or any parent can be removed or inserted, and a child can change its parent. When parent is removed, its children should be also removed. And all this should be done it multi-threaded environment, so I need thread-safe reads (I will use read-only lock for key searching and read-write lock for insertion/deletion/re-parenting). What data structure would you recommend?

Added:

Currently I'm trying to implement it using uthash library ( http://uthash.sourceforge.net/ ):

```
struct parent
{
    uint64_t uid;
    time_t mtime;
    struct ldata data;
    struct child *first_child;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
};

struct child
{
    uint64_t uid;
    time_t mtime;
    struct ldata data;
    struct parent *parent;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
};

struct parent *parents_list = NULL;
struct child *children_list = NULL;
```

The problem is when a new child arrives it ends up being at the tail and
is not connected with its "brothers".

Comment: What do you mean by "lookup"?

Comment: The naive approach: Let each child have a prev, next and parent pointer, and give each parent a pointer to the first child -- i.e. keep doubly-linked list of children. All the pointers should be atomic, to allow lockfree manipulation of the relationship structures.

Comment: By lookup I mean if an object (parent or child) has uID XXXX and I have that uID, I want to get the address of the structure object in the memory.

Comment: I see. O(1) lookup can be done with a hash table, I suppose. If the IDs are contiguous, a simple array might even do the trick. (I.e. a hash table with trivial, perfect hash function.)

Comment: IDs are not contiguous, they are 64-bit unique IDs. And yes, I also tend to use hash tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

1. A hash table for parents.
2. A separate hash table for children.
3. A link in each child to its parent.
4. A link in each child to its next and prev siblings (double linked list).
5. A link in each parent to its first child.

The hash tables may not be quite O(1) lookup, but they will be close.  You can probably use an existing, well-polished library for them.

In terms of thread safety, you could have mutexes for both hashes (for item insertion/deletion), and also a mutex in each parent, for when it or any of its children are being manipulated.  Beware of deadlocks, of course: e.g. if changing a child's parent requires locking both the old and new parents, make sure you do them in a consistent order!

Finding lock-free structures would be even better, of course, but I can't really advise you there, except to research and see if you can find any that seem to fit.

Comment: Thank you, yes multi-threaded programming is very error-prone

Comment: Are B+Trees lock free or they would be an overkill for this problem?

Comment: B+ Trees (and trees in general) can have more than two levels, so a node can be parent and child at the same time.  It doesn't seem to fit your specs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
struct child;  /* Forward declaration */

struct parent {
    int child_count;
    /* Other info */
    struct child child[];  /* Flex array, must be the last field */
};

struct child {
    struct parent *parent;
    /* Other info */
};

struct parent *parent_registry;  /* Array of parents, index is the ID */
struct child *child_registry;  /* Array of children, index is the ID */
```

Maybe it's too simplistic, specially when it comes to reparenting as you will have to shift array slices, but it may be a good start.  Or you could preallocate (i.e. amortized allocation) and link together (by array index) all free array positions to minimize memory moves.

Comment: Thank you friend, I didn't know about those flex array, gone to rtfm :)